# How do query joins work in MPP databases?

Tags: database, join, greenplum, bigdata

I was wondering how SQL joins work in MPP databases like Greenplum, if I wanted to join between two large tables which are distributed across multiple segment nodes, then how is the data processed?

Does the master node grab all relevant data from all nodes and then do the joining and return the resultset? Wouldn't this potentially be a big bottleneck if you were to do many of these types of table joins?

I found the following from [here](http://blog.ness-ses.com/big-data-101-massively-parallel-processing):

> An MPP database tries to segment the data across multiple servers so that each server node can work independently of the others. For example, to perform a JOIN between a large table and a small table, an MPP database will store on each node a subset of rows from the large table, along with a copy of the entire small table. Each node can then perform the JOIN independently of the other nodes, thus eliminating the bottlenecks created by shared resources. This enables massively parallel processing, where a large query can be decomposed into a set of smaller queries, each of which runs independently on a separate server.

This specifically talks about joins with a small table, but mentions nothing about joining two large tables..

Comment: This blog should be helpful in getting the understanding:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960734/how-do-query-joins-work-in-mpp-databases

Answer (score 2):

If the two tables are distributed by the same key, then the join happens local to each segment.  If you are joining two very large tables, it is recommended you distribute the tables by the same key.

In the case when the two tables that aren't distributed by the same key, Greenplum will use the statistics of the tables to copy the data from the smaller table to the location of the larger one to perform the join.  Now, it doesn't move everything.  It only moves the data it needs.

Let's say you have forecast and actual tables that are really large and distributed by different keys.  Actual is larger than forecast and your comparison filters forecast for just a single month.  Greenplum will create a slice that queries just the forecast table for that month and then send the results to the other segments to be joined to the actual table. Realize this is done in parallel on each segment making it extremely fast and scalable.

The master creates the query plan and manages the execution but data isn't sent to the master until the query completes.  The query is handled by the segments.  So no, the master node does not "grab all relevant data from all nodes and then do the joining and return the resultset".

Answer (score -1):

Also the best practice paper here: (https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/204910827-White-Paper-Pivotal-Greenplum-GPDB-Best-Practices-) described the colocated-join and distributions.

Hope those are helpful.